# Angular Material Cards don't fill entire row

Tags: angular, angular-material

New to Angular Material, trying to make a page with some cards that have photos but it seems the default layout for mat-card is that they stack vertically and don't fill out the space in the row to the right.  I've tried wrapping the cards in a div with about a half dozen varieties of flex layouts, none of which have had any effect.

```
<mat-card
  *ngFor="let photo of photos_brazil">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>{{photo.title}}</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>{{photo.subTitle}}</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <img mat-card-image src="{{photo.img_source_small}}" alt="{{photo.alt}}">
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>{{photo.content}}</p>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>


mat-card {
  max-width: 410px;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to solve this is to put a `.card-wrapper` div around the `mat-card`'s `*ngFor` loop (so you don't have to battle with Angular Material's default styling) and give that some styling. I chose for `display: grid` instead of `flex` because it gives more control how to present your data.

```css
.card-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

`grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);` is showing the amount of items (2) per row and it will repeat the rows until all items are displayed. `gap` is setting the space between the grid items. Read more [about grid-template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) columns and [gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) at MDN.

See [this simple example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udft65?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcard-fancy-example.css) on how the content is displayed based on above styling.

Comment: This works for me, thank you, much appreciated.  Yes it seems Angular Material has some default styling that is difficult to customize (for beginners like me).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
mat-card {
  width: calc(100% - 70px);
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
}
```